# fragment is not responding the second time opened

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewPager that contains two fragments (B,C) inside a fragment (A), when you open the app for the first time, the FirebaseRecyclerOptions is working good in fragments B,C and you can see the items in the fragments (B,C) inside the ViewPager.

The problem starts when you exit the fragment (A) when it pauses and destroys, and then returns to it (A) again, then, it is not showing the items inside the ViewPager, fragments(B,C).

I looked at the logs, and on the second time opening fragment (A), the fragments(B,C) are not *attach, create, start, resume* nothing.

the main fragment (A) (in this fragment there is the viewPager)

```
public class myEventsFragment extends Fragment {
    
public myEventsFragment() {}

public static myEventsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    myEventsFragment fragment = new myEventsFragment();

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_events, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG,"dStart");

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    viewPager=(ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperList);
   
   
    myFragmentChoseOne=view.findViewById(R.id.myEventsFragmentChose);
    myFragmentChoseTow= view.findViewById(R.id.joinedEventsFragmentChose);
    userName.setText(myuser.getName()+" "+myuser.getLname());
    ProductRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").orderByChild("email").equalTo(StaticValues.getUser().getEmail());
    ProductRef2 =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("EventJoiners").orderByChild("userId").equalTo(StaticValues.getUid());
  
    

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    Query myRef = database.getReference().child("Events").orderByChild("email").equalTo(StaticValues.getUser().getEmail());
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            eventNum=(int)snapshot.getChildrenCount();
            eventNumber.setText(Integer.toString(eventNum));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }

    });

    myFragmentChoseOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    });

    myFragmentChoseTow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
    });


    pagerViewAdepter=new PagerViewAdepter(getFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerViewAdepter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
} 
}
```

Fragment(B) (inside the ViewPager)

```
public class FragmentMyEventSwiper extends Fragment {


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myevent_swiper,null);
    }

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
   
    recycleView= view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView_myEvents);
    //recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    ProductRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").orderByChild("email").equalTo(StaticValues.getUser().getEmail());
    ProductRef2 =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("EventJoiners").orderByChild("userId").equalTo(StaticValues.getUid());
    recycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseDatabase database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


    ProductRef2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot myrow:snapshot.getChildren()){
                eventCode.add(String.valueOf(myrow.child("eventCode").getValue()));
          sCode.add(String.valueOf(myrow.child("sCode").getValue()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    for (int i=0;i<sCode.size();i++){

        String s=sCode.get(i);
        Query ff2=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Schedule").orderByChild("eventCode").equalTo(s);
        ff2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot myrow:snapshot.getChildren()){
                    String st=String.valueOf(myrow.child("date").getValue().toString());
                    dateList.add(st);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
    
    final FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Event> options=
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Event>()
                    .setQuery(ProductRef,Event.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, myEventsViewHolder> adapter=
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, myEventsViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myEventsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Event model) {

                    Query query=db2.getReference().child("Events").orderByChild("uploadDate").equalTo(model.getUploadDate());

                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                            for(DataSnapshot myrow:snapshot.getChildren()){
                                stt=myrow.getKey();
                            }

                            holder.uploadDate.setText(model.getUploadDate());
                            holder.movieName.setText(model.getMovieName());
                            splitStr = Arrays.asList(model.getPic().split(","));
                                                 
                           }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });            
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public myEventsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view =LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.myevents_events_cardview,parent,false);
                    myEventsViewHolder holder=new myEventsViewHolder(view);
                    return holder;
                }
            };
    recycleView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}
}
```

**ViewPager**

```
 public class PagerViewAdepter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public PagerViewAdepter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment=null;

    switch (position){

        case 0:
             fragment=new FragmentMyEventSwiper();
        break;
        case 1:
            fragment=new FragmentJoinersEventSwiper();
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
}
```

**XML Fragment (A)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Black"
android:id="@+id/fragment_my_events"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Fragments.myEventsFragment">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constrant_layout_myEvente_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

   

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myEventsFragmentChose"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="My Events"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/joinedEventsFragmentChose"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Joined Events"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/swiperList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="450dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**XML Fragment inside ViewPager(B)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_myevent_swiper"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleView_myEvents"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The main problam is that the fragment B,C are working good at the first time, but when you go out fragment A and return they dont even get called. please help i have been stack on this problam a lot of time. thanks